# Size of packaging of Battery Box 88015

Tags: technic, powered-up, size, packaging

I am interested in the dimensions of the packaging of this [product](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/battery-box-88015). I am able to find only the dimensions of the battery box itself, but not the box.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The packaging's dimensions are just slightly bigger than the battery box in it (it fits with little headroom, and room for a booklet). Specifically, 8 x 7.5 x 4.5 cm (ref. [88015-1 (Original Box Entry)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=88015-1)).

Comment: Thank you. I have ordered this component. I will confirm the dimensions here after I receive it.

Answer (score 0):

I received the component today. The exact dimensions are 43 mm x 72 mm x 77 mm.